# Can I use a .006" (.15mm) orifice mist nozzle on a mid-pressure patio misting system?

Tags: water-pressure, patio, cooling, evaporative-cooling

Specifically, the pressure is around 200 PSI. I get the impression from what I have Googled that .006 and below may only work for high-pressure systems.

Comment: What do you consider high pressure? 1500Bar comes to mind.

Comment: Have you got a drill? Holes can be made larger...but a different approach would be to use an **impingement misting nozzle** which has a fairly large hole (harder to clog), operates at low pressure, yet produces a very fine mist through the power of applied physics. The stream of water hits (impinges upon) a flat surface held in front of it, becomes a disk or cone, and then surface tension does the rest. Mine were inexpensive plastic irrigation nozzles and are designed to work as low as 25 PSI supply, yet they make a very fine mist.

Comment: @Ecnerwal read about the intended application and the nozzle size

Comment: Take a #80 and turn it into a 0.0135" hole - or get suitable parts...

Comment: @SolarMike 1000 psi? I'm not sure what the cutoff would be for a high pressure system - but the kind that they use in restaurants so that the customers don't get all wet.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I hadn't heard of impingement nozzles. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Can you please post a link to the impingement nozzles you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your original question, I would guess that a .006 would not work with a mid-level pressure system.  It appears that the smallest size would be .012" for the mid-level pressure system.

This write-up for a .008 orifice (which is larger) states that it should not be used with pressure below 250 psi.  So the .006 would definitely need a high-pressure misting system, i.e.,1000 psi.

Also most of the specifications for .006-008" orifice by the major misting vendors are associated with high pressure system usage.

The .006" is the smallest size listed for high-level systems (750-1000 psi) so it is highly unlikely that it would work for a mid-level system at 200 psi.

[image]

Comment: I replaced my .012s that came with my misting system with these .008s: https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B08FT9NVJF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 While looking around for .006s, many mentioned that they were specifically for high pressure, but some did not so I wasn't sure.

Comment: After some more search, I think you are right concerning .006.